# Check if entry NOT EXISTS in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to insert data from one table that was imported from an Excel file into another table with the same exact columns. When I go to insert all the data

```
    INSERT INTO [NQL_RawData].[dbo].[WM_MFGPNs]
    ([Manufacturer],[MPNWP],[MFGPN],[Cage],[Url],[DataSheetUrl],[Description],[Status],[NRND],[RoHS],[PbFree],[LOT],[LeadTime],[AddedOn],[AddedBy])

    SELECT [Manufacturer],dbo.BuildPNWP([MFGPN],0),[MFGPN],[Cage],[Url],[DataSheetUrl],[Description],[Status],[NRND],[RoHS],[PbFree],[LOT],[LeadTime],[AddedOn],[AddedBy]

    FROM [NQL_RawData].[dbo].[wm_BulkImport] WHERE Manufacturer = 'MFG NAME'
```

it comes up with this error message

Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_MFGPNs_1'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.WM_MFGPNs'.
The statement has been terminated.

So I changed the query to include WHERE NOT EXISTS

```
    INSERT INTO [NQL_RawData].[dbo].[WM_MFGPNs]
    ([Manufacturer],[MPNWP],[MFGPN],[Cage],[Url],[DataSheetUrl],[Description],[Status],[NRND],[RoHS],[PbFree],[LOT],[LeadTime],[AddedOn],[AddedBy])

    SELECT [Manufacturer],dbo.BuildPNWP([MFGPN],0),[MFGPN],[Cage],[Url],[DataSheetUrl],[Description],[Status],[NRND],[RoHS],[PbFree],[LOT],[LeadTime],[AddedOn],[AddedBy]

    FROM [NQL_RawData].[dbo].[wm_BulkImport] 

    WHERE NOT EXISTS( 
    SELECT [MFGPN] 
    FROM [NQL_RawData].[dbo].[WM_MFGPNs]
    WHERE Manufacturer = 'MFG NAME'     
    )
```

But I still receive the same error message. Any ideas?

Comment: What's your PRIMARY KEY?  Your `NOT EXISTS` should be checking that the key doesn't exist instead of checking the `manufacturer` column...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a wild guess, the PK of WM_MFGPNs isn't Manufacturer, but another column, such as MFGPN.
Assuming this to be the case, your insert becomes

```
INSERT INTO [NQL_RawData].[dbo].[WM_MFGPNs]
    ([Manufacturer],[MPNWP],[MFGPN],[Cage],[Url],[DataSheetUrl],[Description],[Status],[NRND],[RoHS],[PbFree],[LOT],[LeadTime],[AddedOn],[AddedBy])

    SELECT [Manufacturer],dbo.BuildPNWP([MFGPN],0),[MFGPN],[Cage],[Url],[DataSheetUrl],[Description],[Status],[NRND],[RoHS],[PbFree],[LOT],[LeadTime],[AddedOn],[AddedBy]

    FROM [NQL_RawData].[dbo].[wm_BulkImport] blkimp

    WHERE
       Manufacturer = 'MFG NAME' -- Your original import filter
    AND NOT EXISTS -- Prevent duplicate insertions
    ( 
    SELECT [MFGPN] 
    FROM [NQL_RawData].[dbo].[WM_MFGPNs] mfgpn
    WHERE blkimp.MFGPN = mfgpn.MFGPN
    )
```

**Edit** : OK, Your table has a Composite Primary Key (i.e. the combination of 2 or more fields comprises a unique key).

```
INSERT INTO [NQL_RawData].[dbo].[WM_MFGPNs]
    ([Manufacturer],[MPNWP],[MFGPN],[Cage],[Url],[DataSheetUrl],[Description],[Status],[NRND],[RoHS],[PbFree],[LOT],[LeadTime],[AddedOn],[AddedBy])

    SELECT [Manufacturer],dbo.BuildPNWP([MFGPN],0),[MFGPN],[Cage],[Url],[DataSheetUrl],[Description],[Status],[NRND],[RoHS],[PbFree],[LOT],[LeadTime],[AddedOn],[AddedBy]

    FROM [NQL_RawData].[dbo].[wm_BulkImport] blkimp

    WHERE
       Manufacturer = 'MFG NAME' -- Your original import filter
    AND NOT EXISTS -- Prevent duplicate insertions
    ( 
    SELECT [MFGPN] 
    FROM [NQL_RawData].[dbo].[WM_MFGPNs] mfgpn
    WHERE blkimp.MFGPN = mfgpn.MFGPN
          AND blkimp.Manufacturer = mfgpn.Manufacturer
    )
```

Comment: okay i tried that code, and I still get the same error message.
the WM_MFGPN table has 2 PKs, one is Manufacturer, and the other is MPNWP. I am not checking either of these columns to see if they already exist, I want to see if the MFGPN already exists for the specified manufacturer.

Comment: How can a table have 2 primary keys?  makes my head spin trying to wrap it around that concept ;)  maybe you mean it has a unique index?

Comment: Manufacturer(PK, varchar(100), not null) MPNWP(PK, varchar(32), not null) MFGPN Cage Url....etc i dont know how it has 2 PKs maybe one is a unique index, but they have it formatted to look like a PK? but I to be more specific of what I'm trying to do, I am trying to take a table called "BulkImport" and insert everything from it into a huge table called "MFGPNs" which has thousands of manufacturers. The problem is that some of the entries exist already. The most important part of the entry is the MPNWP which is the (Manufacturer Part w/o Punctuation). This has to be different for every entry.

Comment: @phplearner07 - Updated :) It does seem a bit surprising that MPNWP isn't unique on its own - it means that more than one Manufacturer has a part called 'XYZ1234' etc.

Comment: wow that is weird to think of. ive never noticed that occuring though, then again we are working with millions of parts.
I'm using the code you posted above and I'm still receiving the same duplicate key error. any more ideas?

Comment: Ouch. A difference in Case Sensitivity between the Bulk Import and WM_MFGPN tables? Possible difference in the length of the fields MFGPN and Manufacturer in the 2 tables causing truncation? Can you do a sp_help of both tables and post into your Q please?

Comment: We solved the problem! there were a couple problems. the bulk import table wasn't keyed the same so it had many duplicate entries, also we weren't checking both Manufacturer and MPNWP against eachother in both tables to see if not exists together.

AND NOT EXISTS
    ( SELECT '' FROM [NQL_RawData].[dbo].[WM_MFGPNs] mfgpn
     WHERE (mfgpn.[Manufacturer] = blkimp.[Manufacturer]) AND (mfgpn.[MPNWP] = blkimp.[MPNWP])
    )